# How do I setup the dotenv file in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I am trying to use the `dotenv` NPM package and it is not working for me. I have a file `config/config.js` with the following content:

```js
'use strict';
    
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.load();
console.log('config');
```

I have another file `.env` at the root of my application folder. I also have an environment variable `TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID`.

This is the process I go through while trying to use the environment variables in a certain function:

```
$ node
> require('./config/config.js');
config
{}
> process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID
undefined
```

I defined the `TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID` in my .env file but as soon as I try to output the value in my console, I get an error stating that the variable is undefined.

I will be very grateful for any support in troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: Works for me, in both the REPL and running the script. What version of node are you using and can you show an example of your .env file?

Comment: I was added the semicolon in the .env file that cause this error.

Answer (score 160):

In my case, every time I tried to get a key from the `.env` file using `process.env.MY_KEY`, it returned `undefined`.

I suffered from this problem for two hours just because I named the file something like `keys.env` which is not considered to be a `.env` file.

So here is the troubleshooting list:

1. The filename should be **`.env`** (I believe `.env.test` is also acceptable).
2. Make sure you are **requiring it as early as possible** in your application using this statement `require('dotenv').config();`
3. The `.env` file should be in the **root directory** of your project.
4. Follow the "file writing rules" like `DB_HOST=localhost`, no need to wrap values in double/single quotes.

Also, check the [documentation of the package on the NPM site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

Comment: moved `.env` file to the root directory of the project it worked.

Comment: Well thank you very much for your input! This was my issue. Potentially just saved me and others two+ hours.

Comment: Agreed, after my project slowly expanded this import got moved down, this saved me a good amount of time.  cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just lost an hour debugging because in my code editor it looked like the .env file was in the root directory. It was not...

Comment: I'd named mine "twitter.env" instead of just ".env".   *sigh*

Comment: Yup. After i saved my file to windows and reuploaded to my server, the . in front got removed...

Comment: excellent tips!! just one addition - check if the db is correct - db names are case sensitive!

Comment: It is almost always something this simple! For me just now I had my .env inside my Views folder.

Comment: This string from dotenv module:
`let dotenvPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.env')`
it defines path to specifically '.env' file so, .env.test probably wouldn't work. Didn't test though.

Comment: I was using `:` instead of `=` in my .env. i.e. `SOMETHING: something` instead of `SOMETHING = something`

Answer (score 73):

I solved this using:

```
require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname + '/.env'})
```

or with an absolute path:

```
C:\\asd\\auhsd\\.env
```

If it does not find the `.env` file, it will return `undefined`.

Comment: Perfect! I needed this because I was running my `NodeJS` project as a service (roughly [following this tutorial](https://do.co/2Qyz9tx)), and it turns out that in that case the service cannot find the `.env` file. Specifying the absolute path was the solution!!

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Using this in a containerized environment, and not sure if that was the cause, but if you are using docker and having trouble, try this fix!

Answer (score 69):

Save yourself some troubleshooting time and log your require call, like so:

```
console.log(require('dotenv').config())
```

You should see an error with more detailed info on the problem.

Comment: You can take this even further and add {debug: true} in the options.

console.log(require('dotenv').config({debug: true}));

Comment: Be careful with the `console.log(require('dotenv').config({debug: true}));` and `console.log(require('dotenv').config())`, because it reveals all your secrets. As long as it doesn't stay (too long) in the logs, it's "fine". Otherwise, you might basically assume these have been compromised. The `debug` option gave me only `[dotenv][DEBUG] did not match key and value when parsing line X:` and `[dotenv][DEBUG] "MY_SECRET" is already defined in 'process.env' and will not be overwritten` logs multiplied by number of secrets. Not sure if it added anything to my case, but upvote for something new ;)

Answer (score 24):

Had the same issue recently. Check your `.env` file and use equal sign not colon. Here's an example:

```
key=value
```

instead of:

```
key:value
```

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem. I realized my file was somehow encoded in `UCS-2 BE BOM`. Converting my `.env` file to `UTF-8` fixed it (you can easily do that using Notepad++, for example).

Comment: You saved my day! I used the echo command in a powershell script to generate the .env file via TFS but that was saved in UCS-2 encoding. So now i make sure powershell saves it as utf-8 and all works fine!

Answer (score 8):

i didn't put my environment variables in the right format as was in the dotenv module documentation e.g. i was doing export TWILIO_CALLER_ID="+wwehehe" and so the dotenv module wasn't parsing my file correctly. When i noticed that i removed the export keyword from the declarations and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and I tried 4 hours to find the fault. In my case, it was bizarre.

When I tried "node app.js", it worked. When I wanted a daemon to start it, it did not work.

How did I solve my problem?
I replaced:

```
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.load();
```

with:

```
var dotenv = require('dotenv').config({path: path.join(__dirname, '.env')})
```

Comment: Instead of using `__dirname` just use `process.env.PWD`

Answer (score 8):

Make sure that variables are not already set. [**Dotenv won't override them.**](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#what-happens-to-environment-variables-that-were-already-set)

If variables are set then you will have to remove them. In powershell you can use the following command - [as mentioned here](https://www.itprotoday.com/management-mobility/powershell-one-liner-deleting-environment-variables):

```
Remove-Item Env:\MyTestVariable
```

Comment: Thanks! This was my problem. I for some reason defined my env. variable like `DATABASE_URL=` in my shell, but forgot about it. It didn't show up at all in my `process.env`, including as an empty string--so annoying! One `unset DATABASE_URL` later and my .env was being read correctly.

Comment: Glad to letting me know that it helped :)

Comment: +2 for you buddy if I only could

Answer (score 8):

I had a problem also with .env variables not loading and being `undefined`.

What I tried:

index.js:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
import models from './models';
```

models.js

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DATABASE,
    process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    {
        dialect: 'postgres',
    }
);
```

Apparently, because of how loading the imports works in nodejs, the import of models in `index.js` caused that the models.js was executed before `dotenv.config()`. Therefore I got undefined values from process.env.

When I changed models.js to do the dotenv configuration like:

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DATABASE,
    process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    {
        dialect: 'postgres',
    }
);
```

it started to work!

Answer (score 7):

Take care that you also execute your Node script from the **ROOT** folder.

E.g. I was using a testing script in a subfolder called `./bin/test.js`.
Calling it like: `node ./bin/test.js` worked totally fine. 
Calling it from the subfolder like:

```
$ pwd
./bin
$ node ./test.js
```

causes `dotenv` to not find my `./.env` file.

Answer (score 6):

I am using NodeJS on windows 10. I used **process.env.var-name** to access the variables but failed because **it gives me windows path variables as a JSON object**, so I installed dotenv ( npm install dotenv ). **dotenv**  gets process envirnoment variables from your **project's .evn file**

1. npm install dotenv or yarn add dotenv

[image]

2. const dotenv = require('dotenv');
   dotenv.config();

[image]

3. process.env.variable_name

[image]
[image]

1. output

[image]

Comment: I doubt that this helps, or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please explain how this works and why it helps.

Comment: I am using NodeJS on windows 10, when I stringify process.env it gives me windows path variables as a JSON object, so I installed this and it sets process.env to the .env file you created within your project

Comment: Better. Now please [edit] to improve your answer with that additional info, instead of hiding it down here in the comments.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure to set cwd in the pm2 config to the correct directory for any calls to dotenv.config().

Example:
Your index.js file is in /app/src, your .env file is in /app. Your index.js file has this

dotenv.config({path: "../.env"});

Your pm2 json config should have this:
"cwd": "/app/src", "script": "index.js"

You could also use dotenv.config({path: path.join(__dirname, "../.env")}); to avoid the CWD issue. You will still have a problem if you move the .env or the index.js file relative to each other.

Answer (score 5):

**Working Solution:**

If you are using webpack (which you definitely should), use a very handy plugin [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) which solves the issue of reading environment variables from `.env` file

> Make sure `.env` is in root directory of your project.

Steps to install the plugin:

1. `npm i -D dotenv-webpack`
2. In `webpack.config` file:

```
     const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
     module.exports = {
          ...
          plugins: [
                new Dotenv(),
                ...
          ],
          ...
     };
```

Now you can call any environment variable defined in `.env` file using `process.env` in any `js` file

Answer (score 5):

My code structure using is as shown below

```
-.env
-app.js
-build
-src
   |-modules
        |-users
            |-controller
                  |-userController.js
```

I have required .env at the top of my app.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
import express = require('express');
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

The process.env.PORT works in my app.listen function. However, on my userController file not sure how this is happening but my problem was I was getting the secretKey value and type as string when I checked using console.log() but getting undefined when trying it on jwt.sign() e.g.

```
console.log('Type: '+ process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
console.log(process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
```

Result:

```
string
secret
```

jwt.sign giving error

```
let accessToken = jwt.sign(userObj, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET); //not working
```

Error was

```
    Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Secret'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Secret'.
```

My Solution:
After reading the documentation. I required the env again in my file( which I probably should have in the first place ) and saved it to variable 'environment'

```
let environment = require('dotenv').config();
```

console logging environment this gives:

```
{
parsed: {
    DB_HOST: 'localhost',
    DB_USER: 'root',
    DB_PASS: 'pass',
    PORT: '3000',
    ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET: 'secretKey',
  }
}
```

Using it on jwt.sign not works

```
let accessToken = jwt.sign(userObj, environment.parsed.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
```

Hope this helps, I was stuck on it for hours. Please feel free to add anything to my answer which may help explain more on this.

Comment: declare require('dotenv').config(); on top of index.js work ty :) !

Answer (score 4):

**There's a lot of confusion about this topic and in these answers**. I'm not surprised, that no single answer was accepted. Hopefully yet.

[The answer by Basheer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43973629/11127383) indeed solves most of the problems. However, there are few things you still need to know. Especially, if you're coming, like me, from frontend background and wants to add secrets to your frontend. Possibly, related to the introduction of some Server-Side Rendering (SSR) logic in the app.

Most probably you've seen this code in your `webpack` settings in a frontend app to solve the issue, as a frontend developer.

```
/* Custom webpack properties. */
const dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new dotenv(), // Handle environemntal variables on localhost, but on the Server-Side Rendering (SSR). There's no access to "process.env" on the browser.
  ],
};
```

Now, it'll work out fine, if you render on the server (SSR) across your app if the `.env` file is in the root of your project. **However, it might not work if you have some custom server-related settings.** An example of such situation is `Angular Universal`, `Nuxt.js` handles this much easier in which `require('dotenv').config()` in your `next.config.js` and makes you good to go. That's due to difference in philosophies between how `Angular` and `Vue.js` are handling SSR. To get `Angular Universal` app from `Angular` that's just 1 command, but the SSR app isn't as nicely organized as `Nuxt.js`. It comes with a price that to generate `Nuxt.js` app from `Vue.js`, you basically have to generate a new `Nuxt.js` project and copy files due to quite some differences between `Nuxt.js` and `Vue.js` setup. Don't know how `React`/`Next.js` and `Svelte`/`Sapper` solves this, but if similarly to `Angular` then you also might consider reading further.

Now, you've some **server**-related logic in a separated folder called **server** and let say the file is called `main.ts`. Maybe apart SSR in that file, you can also have sending mail (`nodemailer`?) logic. Then you'd like to use `process.env`, but apparently it doesn't work, even though you have the logic defined in `webpack`. That's where the `require('dotenv').config();` is needed, even if you're using different syntax for import (such as `import { Express } from 'express';` for example), `require('dotenv').config();` will work like that. Don't feel confused. As long as `.env` is in the root of your app (don't confuse with `server` folder) and the variables have correct syntax inside that file, e.g.

```
MAIL_ACCOUNT=mymail@mydomain.com
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mydomain.com
MAIL_PORT=587
```

It'll work.

Last scenario, in the SSR app you realised that to host this app you need something called Serverless/Cloud Functions/FaaS. Here, I know only `Firebase` scenario. In your project, to deploy such app you might have `functions` folder, from which you deploy the SSR app to the `Cloud Functions for Firebase`, in this example. What a surprise, on a deployment mail is not working and after hours of figuring out what's happening in the logs you can see `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME returning undefined`. The reason is that [as of today the CLI cannot merge files from other locations and indeed the .env file has to be manually copied to the functions folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65080783/11127383). Once copy/paste the `.env` file to `functions` and deploy, it'll work.

What you can use for debugging is one of those:

```
console.log(require('dotenv').config());
console.log(require('dotenv').config({debug: true}));
```

However, be careful with your secrets, because these will be revealed when your `.env` setup will be done. Trying to access one of the secrets and trying to log its value in the logs might be more secure option. Especially, if you have many secrets and don't want to rewrite all.

Hope so this one post will cover most of the scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was stupid. I created the .env in a text editor, and when I saved it it actually saved as

```
'.env.txt'
```

which was only visible after I did a

```
'ls -a'
```

in terminal and saw the file name.

A quick:

```
mv .env.txt .env
```

And I was in business

Answer (score 3):

The '.env' file should be in the root directory of your node js server file (server.js  or for me).

If you placed the '.env' file at the root of your project, it won't work. My mistake was that I have the server.js file nested in a folder named 'controller'.

So I had to fix it by placing the .env file in the same directory as the server.js file.

Answer (score 3):

For React apps created with the `create-react-app` template, you don't need to use `dotenv` directly. `react-scripts` does that for you.

Simply creates a `.env` file in the top level directory of your project and add all your envs there, but notice that they **MUST** start with `REACT_APP` prefix, otherwise they will be ignored.

More details [in their documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/). I just spent a couple of hours dealing with this and hope it will save you some time.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. I used `dotenv-webpack` and need to define

```
plugins: [
  new Dotenv()
]
```

in **both** webpack production and webpack base files (I use webpack merge).
If was not defined in both files then it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

If you are facing this problem it could be that the environment variable(s) is added/loaded after the file that requires the specific variable

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const morgan = require('morgan');

const passport = require('passport'); //you want to use process.env.JWT_SECRET (you will get undefined)

dotenv.config();
```

in the above case, you will get `undefined` for the `process.env.JWT_SECRET`

So the solution is that you put `dotenv.config()` before `const passport = require('passport');`

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const morgan = require('morgan');
dotenv.config();   
const passport = require('passport'); //you want to use process.env.JWT_SECRET (you will get the value for the enviroment variable)
```

Comment: in my case even before const express = require('express');....that solved my problem !!!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I've created a wrapper JS file in which I have the logic to select the correct variables according to my environment, dynamically.

I have these two functions, one it's a wrapper of a simple dotenv functionality, and the other discriminate between environments and set the result to the process.env object.

```html
setEnvVariablesByEnvironment : ()=>{
  return new Promise((resolve)=>{

   if (process.env.NODE_ENV === undefined || process.env.NODE_ENV ==='development'){
    logger.info('Lower / Development environment was detected');

    environmentManager.getEnvironmentFromEnvFile()
     .then(envFile => {
      resolve(envFile);
     });

   }else{
    logger.warn('Production or Stage environment was detected.');
    resolve({
     payload: process.env,
     flag: true,
     status: 0,
     log: 'Returned environment variables placed in .env file.'
    });
   }


  });
 } ,

 /*
 Get environment variables from .env file, using dotEnv npm module.
  */
 getEnvironmentFromEnvFile: () => {
  return new Promise((resolve)=>{
   logger.info('Trying to get configuration of environment variables from .env file');

   env.config({
    debug: (process.env.NODE_ENV === undefined || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
   });

   resolve({
    payload: process.env,
    flag: true,
    status: 0,
    log: 'Returned environment variables placed in .env file.'
   });
  });
 },
```

So, in my server.js file i only added the reference:

```
const envManager = require('./lib/application/config/environment/environment-manager');
```

And in my entry-point (server.js), it's just simple as use it.

```
envManager.setEnvVariablesByEnvironment()
.then(envVariables=>{
    process.env= envVariables.payload;

    const port = process.env.PORT_EXPOSE;
    microService.listen(port, '0.0.0.0' , () =>{

        let welcomeMessage = `Micro Service started at ${Date.now()}`;
        logger.info(welcomeMessage);

        logger.info(`${configuration.about.name} port configured  -> : ${port}`);
        logger.info(`App Author: ${configuration.about.owner}`);
        logger.info(`App Version: ${configuration.about.version}`);
        logger.info(`Created by: ${configuration.about.author}`);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to literally use no name for the .env file, just have the .env extension and save the file like that and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this just renaming the file to .env
to y file was named config.env , when I renamed to .env , it works.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time going through these fixes. I was developing locally and just had to restart the server because the .env file isn't hot reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

is dotenv installed in your project?

Try to install it using `npm install dotenv` in your project.

Once it is installed load it in any files where you need it using `const env = require('dotenv').config()`.

You can then use in any line where you need to. For example to call port from .env use: `process.env.PORT`

Answer (score 1):

If you use "firebase-functions" to host your sever-side-rendered application, you should be aware of this one:

> error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Codes\url_shortener\functions\.env'

Means you have to store the .env file in the functions folder as well.

Found this one by:

```
console.log(require('dotenv').config())
```

Answer (score 1):

I cloned a repo from Github and went through every one of the suggestions here. After a lot of frustration, I realized that `npm install` did not install any of the modules and my `node_modules` folder was empty the whole time.

QUICK FIX:
1) delete your `node_modules` folder
2) delete your `package-lock.json`
3) run `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv'),
      path   = require('path')
dotenv.config({path: path.join(__dirname, '../.env')})
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I had created a file named .env, but in reality the file ended up being .env.txt.

I created a new file, saved it in form of 'No Extension' and boom, the file was real .env and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

**This is how i fix my issue**

Intially had this in .env of the root of my project

```
const db_port = 90101
const db_host="localhost"
const db_username="name"
const db_password="pwd"
const db_name="db"
```

And all my env variables where undefined.

I fixed it by removing all the const and using just key=value insted of 
const key="value"

```
db_port = 90101
db_host=localhost
db_username=name
db_password=pws
db_name=db
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the same codebase that reads my .env file on my MacBook Pro didn't read the .env file on my staging server ubuntu 18.04, so i tried @user3006381 advice  and i noticed the code is trying to look for .env file in my user directory "/home/myusername/.env" and not in "/home/myusername/project/.env",
if you have any idea why that is happening please add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

On some operating sytems (mostly some linux distros, I am looking at you raspbian), .env files don't work. rename them and import that

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed something here myself.

I've defined `.env` correctly, etc and i'd defined `DATABASE_URL` in there but despite doing so another DATABASE_URL was being referenced, perhaps a global environment variable is referenced if it exists?

Anyhow, I found that when I defined `TEST` and `CONNECTION_STRING` within `.env` these both were referenced correctly where as `DATABASE_URL` continues to not be.

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was creating a vscode extension in which
`__dirname`  was referring to something like `d:\extension\my_extension\out`.

the root folder was `my_extension`, but `__dirname` was pointing to `my_extension\out`

so I fixed it by writing

```js
require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname.slice(0,-3)+'/.env'});
```

Answer (score 0):

i had similar problem. i solved it by trim. Please check, path.resolve may add additional space to end of path.

```js
var path = require('path');
const envPath = path.resolve(process.cwd()+'/config','.env.'+process.env.NODE_ENV).trim()
require('dotenv').config({ path: envPath })
```

my package script is like this to use multiple .env:

```json
 "scripts": {
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=development && nodemon ./bin/www",
    "prod": "set NODE_ENV=production && node ./bin/www"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a react native project using dotenv, the .env file might not change because it's being cached in an IOS build. In XCode, do a Product > Clean Build Folder every time you update the .env

Comment: You can also use `react-native-dotenv` to manage your .env file

Answer (score 0):

```
var dotenv = require('dotenv').config({path: 'D:\\site-checker\\.env'});
console.log(dotenv);
result---
{
  parsed: {
    PORT: '5000',
    HOST: 'http://localhost',
    DATABASENAME: 'test_sitechecker',
    NODE_ENV: 'test'
  }
}
```

Here what I struggled with is my path was wrong, it should with two backslashes and should point exactly where your `.env` file is.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when I moved my server code to a nested folder since dotenv is looking in the root directory by default. On top of that, I was using ES6 module imports so I had to do the following:

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config({ path: "/path/to/envfile/.env" });
```

It did the trick in my case.
As an extra tip, in case you want to use `__dirname` to get the path, if you had set

```
type: "module"
```

in your package.json file like I did, you won't be able to use __dirname. What I did, was to go to the directory where .env file was and create a new file named envpath.cjs (pay attention to .cjs):

```
// envpath.cjs
// a file to return the path as a string

const envpath = __dirname;
module.exports = envpath;
```

Then in my working module I had:

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import envpath from "../envpath.cjs";
dotenv.config({path: envpath + "/.env"});
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case also, every time I tried to get a key from the .env file using process.env.DB_HOST, it returned undefined.

So, My problem was I am using 2 different environment for local and for prod like .env.local and .env.prod and in my package.json file i defined

```
"start": "set NODE_ENV=prod && node index.js",
"start:dev": "set NODE_ENV=dev && nodemon index.js"
```

so here the trick was when i am accessing NODE_ENV variable like

```
require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname + `/.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`})
```

my address is becoming 'MY_FILE_PATH.env.dev '

Its hard to see the space after .env.dev.
So whenever you are using 2 diff env make sure to remove spaces in pacakge.json like this:

```
"start": "set NODE_ENV=prod&&node index.js",
"start:dev": "set NODE_ENV=dev&&nodemon index.js"
```

I hope it will help.

Answer (score -1):

**If you want to use.env file in your node js project. Hear all stapes.**

1 Stape: install dotenv package:

```
npm install dotenv.
```

2 Stape: creates .env file in the root directory.
3 Stape: import dotenv in the main file at the top of the line.

```
import dotenv from "dotenv"
```

4 Stape: after importing all package config the dotenv like that :

```
dotenv.config({path: './env'});
```

It's the path of the env file path: './env'

5 Stape: Added dotenv as an experimental in package.json in the script.

```
"scripts": {"dev": "nodemon -r dotenv/config --experimental-json-modules src/index.js"}
```

if come to any error replace this line "dev": "nodemon -r dotenv/config --experimental-json-modules src/index.js" with this "dev": "nodemon -r dotenv/config src/index.js"

My index.js file:

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import express from "express";
const app = express();

dotenv.config({
  path: "./.env",
});
```

in the script dev line src/index.js this is the path of your index.js file.

NOW YOU CAN ABLE USE YOU .env FILE GLOBAL. THANKS;