# Why dotenv not working in script tag on client-side code

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, jekyll, browserify

Background of the problem: I was trying to use `dotenv` to access environment variables to a Jekyll static site. (not reactjs frontend as most other similar questions)

I already followed all suggestions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43973629/6578716), with only one caveat: I'm not sure whether I added `require('dotenv').config();` as early as possible because I use it in a `<script>` tag (using `browserify` for usage of `require` keyword) before `body` end.

But invocation like `process.env.ENV_VAR` returns `undefined`.

Anyone knows what could be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: One of my speculation is that as I'm live reloading my Jekyll site, there're livereload.js injected in `head` and even before `head`, which may be much earlier than my `require('dotenv').config()` statement.

Answer (score 4):

Realized I asked a quite stupid question.

From this [discussion](https://support.glitch.com/t/access-env-vars-from-client-side/451/2):

> The .env variables are only accessible from the server side. If you
>   expose them on the client side then anyone who visits your page will
>   be able to have access to them so you probably wouldn’t want to do
>   that with things like passwords or secrets.