# Access denied when running by npm start, but everything works when run `node www.js`

Tags: node.js

I am new to node.js and ran into the following problem.
I run my node.js app using

```
cd bin
node www.js
```

and it works fine.

And in my `package.json` I added the following section

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node bin/www.js"
  },
```

now when I type

```
npm start
```

in the terminal(I am using vscode)

my project runs normally.

But when I go to a page where some data should be retrieved from the database I get

```
: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

error.
When I do the same using `node www.js` everythings is ok, data is retrieved from db, and there is no prblem.

So what actually does `npm start`, I think it should do the same as `node www.js` but in fact there is some differences.

what can be the reason of such kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem in my code,
actually absolutely different problem caused `access denied`.
The problem was in not being able to read `.env` file.

My `.env` file is in `bin/` folder and in the same folder I run my project

```
node bin/www.js
```

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973484/node-dotenv-is-not-working)
that the `.env` must be in the root folder, from where the application starts
so because of it

```
npm start
```

didn't work as I understand it doesn't run the application directly from `bin\www.js`
So changing

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

to

```
require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname + '/.env'});
```

solve my problem