# Sendgrid API key not reading correctly from env variable

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, sendgrid

I'm following the setup guide for Sendgrid on Node.js (https://app.sendgrid.com/guide/integrate/langs/nodejs), but I keep getting an API key error.

This is my code:

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
  to: 'test@example.com',
  from: 'test@example.com',
  subject: 'Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
  text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
  html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
};
sgMail
  .send(msg)
  .then(() => console.log('send mail success'))
  .catch(console.log);
```

My API key is setup correctly in my .env file:

```
SENDGRID_API_KEY=SG.oqKbQHcNxxxxxxxxxxxxxkY5B4o
```

This is the error message I'm getting:

```
API key does not start with "SG.".
ResponseError: Unauthorized
    at BE-KeyCon/node_modules/@sendgrid/client/src/classes/client.js:133:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  code: 401,
  response: {
    headers: {
      server: 'nginx',
      date: 'Fri, 12 Jun 2020 21:31:08 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'content-length': '116',
      connection: 'close',
      'access-control-allow-origin': 'https://sendgrid.api-docs.io',
      'access-control-allow-methods': 'POST',
      'access-control-allow-headers': 'Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl',
      'access-control-max-age': '600',
      'x-no-cors-reason': 'https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html'
    },
    body: { errors: [Array] }
  }
}
```

If I set the API key as a string, like so:

```
sgMail.setApiKey('SG.oqKbQHcNxxxxxxxxxxxxxkY5B4o')
```

Then it works. But obviously I can't leave it like this for security reasons. Any idea why it's behaving this way and how I might fix it?

Comment: What does `process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY` evaluate to?

Comment: undefined! I tried all of my environement variables and they all returned undefined. That's weird... The .env file is in my root directory and I am requiring the dotenv library.

Comment: If I run `node -r dotenv/config util/sendgrid.js` then it evaluates correctly to the api key.

Comment: How early are you running `require('dotenv').config()`? Are you making sure it's happening before your call to `process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY`?

Comment: It's in my index.js file, where I initialize the server:
```require('dotenv').config();```
```const server = express();```

Comment: And is your Sendgrid script also loaded somewhere through an `import` or `require` statement that your Express process knows about? Or is it a separate script? The only thing I can think of is that if you're running Sendgrid as a separate process from Express, then it's operating on another thread that wouldn't have access to what Dotenv is providing. If so, you may need to also drop another `require('dotenv').config();` call to your Sendgrid entry script.

Comment: Good point, it was not! However, I added `require('dotenv').config();` to the top of my sendgrid.j file, and I still get the exact same error.

Comment: Hmmmm. I'm fresh out of ideas. Double check the name and location of your .env file, and make sure the contents of your file match the format expected of environment variables. [See the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973484/how-do-i-setup-the-dotenv-file-in-node-js) for more ideas and debugging help.

Comment: I just ran a `console.log(require('dotenv').config());`, and turned out it couldn't find the .env file. I have two main folders in my project, one for frontend and one for backend, and I had the .env file in the BE folder thinking that was my root. I had to move it out to the actual root, and now it's working fine. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Glad you got it all figured out! Feel free to drop in an answer and accept it in case others stumble upon this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the location of the .env file. I had my backend folder nested inside another folder, so I had to move it out to the actual root.

Answer (score 0):

install `dotenv` package from npm and use this piece of code to make sure that it takes the .env file:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') require('dotenv').config();
```

console log the `process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY` to check whether the program is getting the api key.

Answer (score 0):

Used to encounter this problem but simply updating the files didn't quite work out in my case.

Here is how I solve it eventually: 
Include `require('dotenv').config`  in the file that integrates the SendGrid API. 
Go to Heroku app. Click on the "Settings" page and look for "Config Vars".
["Find 'Config Vars' in the 'Settings' page"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjwpg.png)

Press the "Reveal the Config" button and add another key pair.
Set "SENDGRID_API_KEY" as the KEY & set your SG.xxxxxxYourAPIxxx as the value.
Add the key pair and rerun the app.

Answer (score 0):

Single quote the value in your .env file:

```
SENDGRID_API_KEY='SG.oqKbQHcNxxxxxxxxxxxxxkY5B4o'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue I realized my .env.local file was named wrong by missing . in the beginning so make sure your file name is correct and if it still dont work try installing dot dev by this commandnpm install dotenv