# Loopback 4: Specify environment var in the @model

Tags: mongodb, environment-variables, loopback4

I am trying to get the mongodb collection name from an environment variable defined in .env. It looks like the model is initialised before the .env is read.

```
@model({
  name: 'MyType',
  settings: {
    mongodb: process.env.COLLECTION_NAME,
  },
})
```

The process.env.COLLECTION_NAME is, at this point, *undefined*

Any way to externalised the collection name?
Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Node.js does not read from `.env`.

To read from `.env`, we need to utilize the `dotenv` package.

Since models are resolved through the [Booter](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Booting-an-Application.html) during startup, hence we need to call `dotenv.config()` before `app.boot()`.

Update `index.ts` as follows:

```js
// At the top of the file
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

...

// Inside the main function
// dotenv.config() must appear before app.boot()

dotenv.config()
...
app.boot();
app.start();
```

This would cause `dotenv` to overwrite `process.env` with the values in `.env` where necessary.

### Further reading:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv
- [How do I setup the dotenv file in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26973484)

Comment: `Thanks Rifa.`  
  
`Using dotenv, ok elsewhere in the project. `  
  
`The problem is with the model. Looks like this is executed before the .env is read.`  

`The example code here:`  
  
`const mongodbCollection = {`  
  `collection: process.env.COLLECTION_NAME ?? 'my_collection',`  
`};`  
  
console.log(process.env.COLLECTION_NAME);  

and I am getting on the console:  
  
undefined  
Server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/dev/project/v1  
Try http://127.0.0.1:8080/dev/project/v1/ping  
  
This (undefined) shows the model is initialised before the .env read`

Comment: Thanks again. 
Tried, still getting "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

in your

> src/index.ts

```
import {ApplicationConfig, MyApplication} from './application';
require('dotenv').config();
export * from './application';
```

and your .env file in the "root" of your project