# Why have the environment variables in my .env file stopped working?

Tags: node.js, dotenv

My .env has been working forever but stopped working all of a sudden.

.env

```
LOCAL_PORT=4200
JWT_SECRET=afdafuwafjadgaqjfafads
```

server.js

```
require('dotenv').config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || process.env.LOCAL_PORT;
console.log('process.env.PORT', process.env.PORT)
console.log('process.env.LOCAL_PORT', process.env.LOCAL_PORT)

process.env.PORT undefined
process.env.LOCAL_PORT undefined
```

Comment: Do any of the answers [How do I setup the dotenv file in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973484/how-do-i-setup-the-dotenv-file-in-node-js) help?

Answer (score 1):

In many cases this a path issue. I recommend attempting to set the path explicitly and also turning `debug` mode on.

```js
require('dotenv').config({path: path.join(__dirname, '.env'), debug: true})
```